# how to install Pantheon desktop environment on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, desktop-environments, pantheon

How can I install Pantheon desktop environment(stable) on Ubuntu 20.04? Everything I found on the internet was for old version or not working(people said in the comments).

Answer (score 1):

The stable branch does not have 20.04 available yet (Dec. 2020)

You can install the daily builds using the daily PPA.

Here's a good write up on desktop environments for 20.04 (includes Phanteon)

https://itsubuntu.com/top-desktop-environments-for-ubuntu-20-04-lts/

Comment: It took me a while to realise the error `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.` was still coming from the stable repository and I had to `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:elementary-os/stable` first.